How to animate vertical line with scrolling?
I'm trying to animate a vertical line depending on the positions of elements on the page. Here's an example of what I want to achieve.

I tried to do something like this


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const line = document.querySelector('.vertical-line');
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

    let options = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.1
    };

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.classList.remove('hidden');
            } else {
                entry.target.classList.add('hidden');
            }
        });
    }, options);

    sections.forEach(section => {
        observer.observe(section);
    });

    let scrollDirection = 'down';
    let lastScrollTop = 0;

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        let st = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            scrollDirection = 'down';
        } else {
            scrollDirection = 'up';
        }
        lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;

        if (scrollDirection === 'down') {
            line.style.transform = 'translateX(50vw)';
        } else {
            line.style.transform = 'translateX(-50vw)';
        }
    });
});
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
    padding-left: 8.125rem;
    padding-right: 8.125rem;
    align-self: center;

    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-line {
    content: '';
    border-left: 1px solid var(--primary-text);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--primary-text);
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 48.75rem;
    right: 50%;

    transition: transform 1s;
}

@keyframes moveLine {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(50px); }
} */

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
<section id="s1">
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div>
                    <p class="about-text-title">Label1</p>
                    <p class="about-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident nulla iure quod autem amet, ipsa beatae
                        voluptatibus maiores adipisci quae, expedita deserunt laborum architecto corporis dolore. Voluptates tenetur nisi
                        cupiditate?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col vertical-line"></div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>Video frame</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="s2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>Label2</p>
                <p class="about-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident nulla iure quod autem amet, ipsa beatae
                        voluptatibus maiores adipisci quae, expedita deserunt laborum architecto corporis dolore. Voluptates tenetur nisi
                        cupiditate?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>Another video frame</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



The line actually moves depending on the scroll, but it moves to the extreme position of the screen and when I stop scrolling it moves to the place where it is by default (on the left). But most importantly, it does not paint over the elements of section 1 and the elements of section 2 do not appear after it.
I don't really know how to do this. What I actually want to do is "paginate", so that this line will scroll the page, updating the elements.
Please tell me how to do this? I will be glad for any help. p.s. Sorry if I didn't explain it well, I'm really bad at html, css, js.
I tried to reproduce the provided example using javascript and css, but it doesn't work as I wanted.

This isn't the complete solution, because I don't know how you want certain things. Like, if you scroll up, should the animation run? What happens if the user continues to scroll while the bouncing animation is running? Will you have other elements on the page?

I rewrote all CSS and added the vertical line at the top. I also added position: fixed to the #vertical-line and all section > .container elements. I assumed that the vertical line should not hide the video if the user scrolls to the last section.
I skipped the bouncing animation and will leave it to you to solve, but this code should give you a few pointers.


const verticalLineEl = document.getElementById('vertical-line');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

let checkingVerticalScroll = false;
let lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
let sectionHeight;

document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

  if (!checkingVerticalScroll) {
  
    // Only do calculations and update when the screen is actually refreshing
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      updateVerticalLineWidth(lastKnownScrollPosition);
      checkingVerticalScroll = false;
    });

    checkingVerticalScroll = true;
  }
});

const updateVerticalLineWidth = (lastKnownScrollPosition) => {
  const currentSection = calculateCurrentSection(lastKnownScrollPosition);

  verticalLineEl.style.width = calculateVerticalLineWidth(currentSection, lastKnownScrollPosition);
  
  setContainerStackingOrder(currentSection);
}

const calculateCurrentSection = (lastKnownScrollPosition) => {
  let currentSection = Math.ceil(lastKnownScrollPosition * sections.length / window.innerHeight);
  currentSection = Math.min(sections.length, currentSection);
  currentSection = Math.max(1, currentSection);

  return currentSection
}

const calculateVerticalLineWidth = (currentSection, lastKnownScrollPosition) => {  
  let widthVerticalLine = 0;
  
  // Don't animate the last section
  if (currentSection < sections.length) {
    let sectionHeight = sections[currentSection].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    
    const maxWidthVerticalLine = window.innerWidth;

    let scrollInSection = lastKnownScrollPosition - sectionHeight * (currentSection - 1);

    widthVerticalLine = maxWidthVerticalLine * scrollInSection / sectionHeight;

    return widthVerticalLine + 'px';  
  } 
  
  return widthVerticalLine + 'px';
}

const setContainerStackingOrder = (currentSection) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    sections[i].firstElementChild.style.zIndex = (currentSection == i + 1) ? 50 : 0;
  }
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#vertical-line {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: 0% -50%;
  z-index: 100;

  height: 80vh;
  width: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;

  background-color: white;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section > .container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  translate: 0% -50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  
}

.about-text-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  
  width: 50%;
  flex-basis: 1;
}
<div id="vertical-line"></div>

<section id="s1">
  <div class="container" style="z-index: 50">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div>
          <p class="about-text-title">Label1</p>
          <p class="about-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident nulla iure quod autem amet, ipsa beatae voluptatibus maiores adipisci quae, expedita deserunt laborum architecto corporis dolore. Voluptates tenetur nisi cupiditate?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>Video frame</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="s2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="about-text-title">Label2</p>
        <p class="about-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident nulla iure quod autem amet, ipsa beatae voluptatibus maiores adipisci quae, expedita deserunt laborum architecto corporis dolore. Voluptates tenetur nisi cupiditate?
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>Another video frame</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Thanks for the answer, looks great. The way the line "paints over" the element on the right is exactly what is needed. When scrolling, the line overlaps the element on the right and with further scrolling, the line “draws” the element from section 2 and paints the element on the left from section 1, with further scrolling the line draws the element on the left of section 2, and so on. If you scroll up, the animation is reversed. There will be other elements. As I understand it, all the logic of movement is only in javascript and should I go in this direction?

I would probably add a class with a CSS animation for the bouncy effect. There exist scroll-based CSS animations, but the support isn't great yet.

Thanks for the link! There is a lot of useful information in it.
